# Can I install FM radio APK in another phone?

Tags: installation, apk, fm-radio

I have the FMRadio's APK of an old phone with recording feature and I would like to install it in a phone that comes with FM Radio but doesn't have recording feature.

I've tried but it says app was not install but the icon appears in desktop but doesn't run.

Is there a way to make this?

I saw somewhere something like the apk should be copied to system/app folder. But I receive permission denied to copy there.

I tried without success with Spirit Radio and next radio apps. They don't work for my phone model Zenfone2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Zenfone 2 doesn't use a standard radio interface that most phones with FM radio do, the FM radio will only work with the stock radio app on the stock ROM. It uses a proprietary kernel interface that is only in the stock ROM. Other apps do not work.

Comment: Tu acejavelin. I even tried a Samsung J3 fm radio app in a Samsung S6 and doesn't work and both of the same brand.